# android vitamio player get track info

Tags: android, streaming

I have used vitamio plugin in my android application for playing radio streaming (in rtmp, m3u8 and rtsp protocols). Now I want to also to show current playing information, so how can I make this possible? thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It does not look like Vitamio supports this.  You can only find bare info about the track.  You would have to maintain this info via other custom objects at this time.